# Текст не влезает в кнопки aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть бот Python aiogram, в боте есть кнопки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На телефонах текст длиннее 4 символов сокращается, если ли какое-то решение этой проблемы?

Comment: очевидно, что решение только одно - не делать такое количество кнопок

Comment: что вы пытаетесь сделать? Что это? Календарь?

Comment: @1001001, похоже на то...главное, чтобы не возникла идея реализовать периодическую систему химических элементов Менделеева в таком же виде

Comment: без доп. информации мало что можно посоветовать. Но я думаю вам требуется изменить подход к вашей реализации. И подумать над более практичным и менее затратным решением.